# When a list contain a 'Button' element, how can i only find the value of list,but button

Tags: javascript, html

I try to find a value of a list, but there a button is contained in the list, how can i only find value of the list,but the button.

```html
  <div class="list">
    <p class="description">Things that are purple:</p>
    <input type="text" class="description">
    <button class="description">Change list description</button>
    <ul class="list">
         <li>grapes<button>Remove</button></li>
        <li>amethyst<button>Remove</button></li>
        <li>lavender<button>Remove</button></li>
        <li>plums<button>Remove</button></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" class="addItemInput">
    <button class="addItemButton">Add item</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "value of a list"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

```
Array.from(document.querySelector('ul.list').children).map(el => el.innerText)
```

in the case that you want exactly data in the list `li` elements, it's less convenient:

```js
    Array.from(document.querySelector('ul.list').children)
     .map(el => 
       el.childNodes.reduce((p,c) => {
         p += c.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? c: ''
         return p
       }, ''))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the running result don't match my expect, i only want get the result as ' grapes', not 'grapesRemove'

Comment: yeah ... not if there is trailing text ..a mode general solution is to compare Node.TEXT_NODE

Comment: ohh, thanks for your kind, i'll try. document.querySelector('ul.list').children[0].childNodes[0].textContent